# How to display an image from mysql php into android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, blob

I am currently trying to display an image from mysql database into my android program using an image view. However, it does not work the way I wanted to yet. The following is the php code i currently have:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    require 'connect_aircraftoperator.php';

    $image = $db->query("SELECT companyImage FROM company where companyID = 2");

    $getImage = $image->fetch_assoc();
    $upload = $getImage['companyImage'];
    header("Content-type: image/png");

    echo $upload;
?>
```

The code displays the image just fine in the browser. The following is my current android code

```
void getImage() {

    //String imageResult = "";
    //JSONObject jArray = null;
    //String Qrimage;
    //Bitmap bmp;

    try {
        //setting up the default http client
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //specify the url and the name of the php file that we are going to use
        //as a parameter to the HttpPost method
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2//aircraftoperatorapp/leimage.php");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception 1 Caught ");
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);


        //create a string builder object to hold data
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }

        //use the toString() method to get the data in the result
        imageResult = sb.toString();
        is.close();

        //checks the data by printing the result in the logcat
        System.out.println("---Here's my data---");
        System.out.println(imageResult);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception 2 Caught ");
    }

    try {

        //creates json array
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(imageResult);

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 
        {
            //create a json object to extract the data
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            imageTemp = json_data.getString("companyImage"); //gets the value from the php
        }
        lblTesting3.setText(imageTemp);

        byte[] data = Base64.decode(imageTemp, 0);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length,null);

        imgCompany.setImageBitmap(b);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        //System.out.println("Exception 3 Caught ");
        Log.e("lag_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

All I have returning is some text that probably has to do with the image I'm returning. The following text is like this in the beginning:

ÿØÿáhExifMM*vž¤¬(1´2Ò‡iè  ü€' ü€..... and so on.

Is there a way I can convert this into an image that is displayable into my android program with the code I have or do I have to do something more different? I would appreciate anyone would help me! It would mean a lot! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library and you get rid of low-level problems like this. See also my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954830/loading-image-from-url-in-custom-adapter-for-listview-android-studio/29955094#29955094).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're facing with is a simple decoding mistake.

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

is = entity.getContent();
```

The InputStream you're getting from the HttpEntity contains binary image data. So you can simply copy that data into an bytearray:

```
...
Bitmap bitmap;
byte[] image = null;
...

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
copy(in, out, true);
image = out.toByteArray();
in.close();

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
...

public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out, boolean close)
  throws IOException
{
  if (in != null && out != null)
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int count;
    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) 
      out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    if (close)
    {
      in.close();
      out.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it asap! I'll let you know if I have questions

Comment: where in  my code should I put these lines? I tried in multiple places, it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I don't know. It depends on your project layout. Please describe your problem in detail.