# Reducing Image Size at Runtime for Android app

Tags: android, json, image-size

I am parsing a json schema which contains textual info and image urls for my android app. I want to read all the images from the schema and then show them in the gallery view of my android app.

But the problem is, the image urls contain HD pics and it takes a lot of time to load. Is there a way I can reduce the size of those images at run time and then display or can you suggest any improvement tip so that the images could load quickly from the schema?

Thanks

Comment: Since these are URLs you have to download them first, like it or not. Once you got it locally, you can scale it. So what is your question?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski This is the problem actually, I don't want to download the pics because they are taking too much time to download. Is there a way I can download the lower resolution version of the pics from the same url? for e.g. www.url1.jpg contains a HD pic so I want to download the lower resolution version of the same pic using the same url so that it gets downloaded quickly, is it possible? if so then how?

Comment: You seem to NOT understand IT basics I am afraid...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it would have been really good of you if you have replied in simple yes or no rather than judging. Thanks user3541465 for your help :)

Comment: FYI: you accepted answer that is not close to addressing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library, it can resize your images whatever you like and bind it to ImageView. See also my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954830/loading-image-from-url-in-custom-adapter-for-listview-android-studio/29955094#29955094).

But if your images on your server are too big, it all depends on your internet connection, how fast they get to your device.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your image downloaded from url using picasso library. Also it will allow lazy loading of images and you can also set placeholder and error images in your imageview.
You can read complete documentation here: http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)// resizing images
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Comment: But the image should be downloaded first then this can be applied, right?

Comment: no it does not need to be downloaded separately. You have to just pass the url as i have shown in my answer and give the dimensions for resizing image. Picasso library will automatically do rest of the work.

Comment: Picasso will download the whole big image first and then resize it. So this may work but it does not answer your question/whish not to have to download big images.

Comment: @greenapps u r right, but is there any answer to my question? like first resizing and then downloading so it is done quickly?

Comment: Exactly. The server should resize them before the download is started.